# How could the asset pipeline use url_options to automatically append parameters like url_for and link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in one rails 3.2 app, I am doing this.

```
def url_options
  {
    :p1 => value1,
    :p2 => value2
  }.merge(super)
end
```

which works fine. except for the Asset pipeline.
I need these parameters to be appended to all app urls, including css, js, images.

in a separate rails 3.2 app. for a strange reason I ignore.
the same url_options did not work. not only for assets, but did not work at all.
I had to do the following instead.

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:p1] = value1
```

which does not work for assets either.
I'm puzzled. anyone would know of a solution?

thanks

Comment: would anyone know the difference between the two method, please clarify. Why would one work in some situation and sometimes the other is required? and is there other differences between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there you go ! you can monkey patch Sprockets to include your url option helper...

```
module Sprockets
  module Helpers
    module RailsHelper
      def asset_path_with_url_options(source, options = {})
        uri = Addressable::URI.parse(asset_path_without_url_options(source, options))
        default_url_options = url_options.dup.delete_if { |k,v|
          [:host, :port, :protocol, :_path_segments, :script_name].include?(k)
        }
        uri.query_values = default_url_options.merge(uri.query_values || {})
        uri.to_s
      end

      alias_method_chain :asset_path, :url_options
      alias_method :path_to_asset, :asset_path_with_url_options # aliased to avoid conflicts with an asset_path named route
    end
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  # anything using link_to, url_for, etc. uses this automatically.
  def url_options
    {
      :k1 => v1,
      :k2 => v2
    }.merge(super)
  end

end
```

Comment: Made a gem with this patch. https://github.com/mjobin-mdsol/url_options_for_assets